# Can't add more then one image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This code in the ERB only displays one image. I thought it would be a simple fix but I've scoured google trying to find it. Maybe I'm just forgetting something

```
<%=
image_tag ruby.png
image_tag ruby.png %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<%= %>` prints the *result* of the code inside it, not all of it. If you want to display two images, you can do

```
<%= image_tag('ruby.png') %>
<%= image_tag('ruby.png') %>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag('ruby.png') << image_tag('ruby.png') %>
```

or

```
<%
  concat(image_tag('ruby.png'))
  concat(image_tag('ruby.png'))
%>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have a few loops that make 92 images total and I really didn't want to put them each by hand. It creates an error if I use a << on the last line and it duplicates the website twice if I do the concats like you posted. I'll just do an if table.last then else. Thanks again!

Comment: concat is to be used with `<%` not `<%=`

Comment: Awesome! It's great to finally see all my work come together the world needs more people like you. http://www.solidfiles.com/d/8f13ed1776/

Answer (score 0):

If we want to display in the screen, we have to use the equal (=) symbol.

Please modify your code like this..

```
<%=image_tag ('ruby.png') %>

<%=image_tag ('ruby.png') %>
```

ELSE if you have more images. collect it in a array and do the following.

all_images=[image1.png,image2.png,image3.png,image4.png,image5.png,....imagex.png]

then

all_images.each do |image_name|

```
<%=image_tag ('image_name')%>
```

end